# Merge two objects without removing the original properties

Tags: javascript

I have two objects namely `Object1` and `Object2`.

```
var Object1 = {    
     child1: [{name: "google", check: false}, 
       {name: "yahoo", check: false}, {name: "msn", check: false}],
     child2: [{name: "google", check: false}, {name: "yahoo", check: false}],        
};

var Object2 = {
    child1: [{name: "google", check: true}, {name: "yahoo", check: true}],
};
```

I would like to replace the `Object2 Child1` array with `Object1 Child1` array but not removing the properties which are not there in `Object2`.

```
const NewObject = Object.assign({}, Object1, Object2)
```

The above code gives me `NewObject` with only `Object2`. The Final output i am looking at is where the check true property of second object is replaced in primary one.

```
var Object3 = {    
         child1: [{name: "google", check: true}, 
           {name: "yahoo", check: true}, {name: "msn", check: false}],
         child2: [{name: "google", check: false}, {name: "yahoo", check: false}],        
};
```

Comment: [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) only performs a shallow copy. For more intricate merging, you'll need to write your own function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the answer here are based upon the fact that the elements in attributes `child1` have the same index for the same name. If this is not the case let me offer you an alternative. This solution matches the elements inside `child1` based on *name* and not array index.

```js
var Object1 = {child1: [{name: "google", check: false}, {name: "yahoo", check: false}, {name: "msn", check: false}], child2: [{name: "google", check: false}, {name: "yahoo", check: false}]};
var Object2 = {child1: [{name: "yahoo", check: true}, {name: "google", check: true}]};
//                                ^                             ^
// I swapped the elements of Object2.child1 around to better show the
// intention of this specific solution.

function customAssign(obj1, obj2) {
  var result = {};

  // based on the fact that obj2 has a subset of keys of obj1
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj1).forEach(key => {
    var attr1 = obj1[key], 
        attr2 = obj2[key], 
        itemLookup = {};

    if (Array.isArray(attr1) && Array.isArray(attr2)) {
      // based on the fact that the collection of an attribute
      // of obj2 a subset of the same attribue at obj1
      attr2.forEach(item => itemLookup[item.name] = item);
      result[key] = attr1.map(item1 => {
        var item2 = itemLookup[item1.name];
        if (item2 && item2.check) return item2;
        return item1;
      });
    } else {
      result[key] = attr2 || attr1;
    }
  });

  return result;
}

console.log(
  customAssign(Object1, Object2)
);
```

This solution has still some limitations. It is now based upon the fact that `Object2` has an subset of keys of `Object1`. Furthermore if both `Object1` and `Object2` have an array attribute, the elements present at the `Object2` attribute must be a subset of the elements present at the `Object1` attribute (based upon *name*). Lastly, two (or more) items in an array collection in `Object2` may not have the same *name*, if this does happen the later of the two is used.

I hope the above will give you some inspiration, even if this is not the exact solution you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think the merge function from [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#merge) is what you are looking for. Or you can build your own function for merging object recursively, but the end result is going to be something very similar to what Lodash has achieved.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, just use for..in to iterate `Object1` and check if Object2 has the same key. If it has same key like `child1` then use `Object.assign`. Note in Object.assign the value of common keys will be updated according to the order of the objects. For example in `Object.assign({}, Object1[keys], Object2[keys])` it will create a new object with keys and values from both Object1 & Object2 , but if there is a common key between these two then values of `keys` in Object2 will update the same key in `Object1`

```js
var Object1 = {
  child1: [{
      name: "google",
      check: false
    },
    {
      name: "yahoo",
      check: false
    }, {
      name: "msn",
      check: false
    }
  ],
  child2: [{
    name: "google",
    check: false
  }, {
    name: "yahoo",
    check: false
  }],
};

var Object2 = {
  child1: [{
    name: "google",
    check: true
  }, {
    name: "yahoo",
    check: true
  }],
};
let Object3 = {};

for (let keys in Object1) {
  if (Object2.hasOwnProperty(keys)) {
    Object3[keys] = Object.assign({}, Object1[keys], Object2[keys])
  } else {
    Object3[keys] = Object.assign({}, Object1[keys])
  }
}
console.log(Object3)
```

Comment: From the [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) documentation. *"Primitives will be wrapped, null and undefined will be ignored."* meaning that the *if*-statement can be removed. Furthermore it might be worth noting that the array is merged based on element position and not based on element name. If arrays are always delivered in the correct order this might not be an issue though.

Comment: @3limin4t0r hey thaks for sharing , i overlooked that `if` part. Thanks for bringing it up

Answer (score 0):

Use `merge` function of [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#merge),

```
var Object1 = {    
     child1: [{name: "google", check: false}, 
       {name: "yahoo", check: false}, {name: "msn", check: false}],
     child2: [{name: "google", check: false}, {name: "yahoo", check: false}],        
};

var Object2 = {
    child1: [{name: "google", check: true}, {name: "yahoo", check: true}],
};

_.merge(Object1, Object2);
console.log(Object1);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zar6kh1n/)

Answer (score 0):

You can both use lodash or using [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), you can do something like this:

```
var Object3 = {
    child1: [...Object2.child1],
    child2: [...Object1.child2],
};
```